# Smooth horizontal scroll in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have a slider and I wanted to implement a smooth scroll after clicking on an arrow. Below is the code which is called once the arrow is clicked. For the smooth scroll, I used setInterval. Each 10 miliseconds I am itterating scrollLeft until it reaches either `(scroll/ 10)` or the end of the container.

The problem is that if for example `scroll` variable is 795, it should iterate by 79.5 but the scrollLeft attribute always strips the decimals and only iterates by 79 so the condition is never met.

What is the best possible way of solving this?

```
                    var slides = document.querySelector('#jackpots');                    
                    var scroll = slides.scrollLeft + slides.offsetWidth;
                    var interval = setInterval(function(){
                        if(slides.scrollLeft === scroll || slides.scrollWidth === (slides.scrollLeft + slides.clientWidth))
                            clearInterval(interval);
                        else
                            slides.scrollLeft += (scroll / 10);
                    }, 10)
```

Comment: Do you need to use strict equality for clearing your interval?  Or would `>=` or `<=` work?

Comment: Strict equallity would be better for me. I know about the possibility of >== but that wouldn't be so precise... @Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
else
   slides.scrollLeft += (scroll / 10);
```

becomes

```
else {
    if (Math.abs(slides.scrollLeft - scroll) < (scroll / 10))
        slides.scrollLeft = scroll;
    else
        slides.scrollLeft += (scroll / 10);
}
```

math.abs part checks to see if you are near the destination before making sliders.scrollLeft = scroll otherwise it scrolls as you currently have it.

Comment: Been using Lua today which uses math - Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollIntoView`  instead of setting scrollLeft and set the scroll behaviour to smooth:

```js
document.querySelector('#jackpots').scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

This is built in in new browsers and your approach won't work across shadow doms and cross-domain iFrames.

Comment: but I want to scroll by width not to scroll on a specific element

Comment: Make a new invisible element relative to on where you want and scroll to it.